# Tor Browser on ARM - Message regarding background update

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, mac

My setup is Windows 10 (ARM insider Preview), on a Mac (the new ARM based processor).

I installed Tor Browser and on start-up it says that an update has occurred in the background and I need to restart the browser. I do this, but all I get is the same message.

How do I resolve this please?
Thanks

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you should make a [bug report](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues).